# Jquery targeting elements within parent div

Tags: jquery

I have a page set up with a bunch of products, and you can click on the color swatch to change the color of the product. The color swatch/product switch is all set up with a photo gallery plugin. I'm just trying to make it so if you're looking at a black phone, the black color swatch has a class of "selected."

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class='swatches'>
       <a href='{..}images/phones/products/droid-razr-m-black.jpg' rel='enlargeimage' rev='targetdiv:loadarea1,trigger:click,preload:yes,fx:none'><img src='{..}images/verizonspecials/phones/swatch-black.gif' alt='Black' class='selected'/></a>
       <a href='{..}images/phones/products/droid-razr-m-white.jpg' rel='enlargeimage' rev='targetdiv:loadarea1,trigger:click,preload:yes,fx:none'><img src='{..}images/verizonspecials/phones/swatch-white.gif' alt='White'/></a>
       <a href='{..}images/phones/products/droid-razr-m-blue.jpg' rel='enlargeimage' rev='targetdiv:loadarea1,trigger:click,preload:yes,fx:none'><img src='{..}images/verizonspecials/phones/swatch-blue.gif' alt='Blue'/></a>
 </div>
```

I have multiple items on the page, so that swatches div is duplicated a bunch of times. I started with this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.swatches img').click(function() {
    $('img.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
});
```

But that removed the selected class from all of the images, not just the ones inside that particular swatches div. So then I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.swatches img').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
});
```

But that didn't do anything - every image I click gains the class of "selected", but the class is never removed from any of the other images.

Answer (score 0):

Those interior images are not the siblings of the swatches div, they are its children. You also need to add 'selected' to the right child

```
$('.swatches').click(function(event) {
  var clicked = event.target;
  $(this).children().children().removeClass('selected');
  $(clicked).addClass('selected');
});
```

This should work, but IMO a better solution is to have a 'select' div with an overlay image (like a selector box) and transparency, then just move that div's position to the right color on click, instead of assigning and removing classes

Comment: The `'.swatches img'` selector referenced the `img` Elements, though.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't do anything, the class of selected isn't added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

The Images are embedded in Anchor Elements, thus they have no siblings.
Use

```
$("img", ($(this).parent().parent())[0]).removeClass('selected');
```

Instead.

Comment: This doesn't seem to remove the class, when I click a new image it just adds the class without removing it from the previous image.